# Use time machine to sync 2 laptops

Tags: time-machine

I have two MacBooks.

1. MacBook 1 is my Air, it has been at my office  in quarantine for over a year. I get it back tomorrow.
2. MacBook 2 was my old MacBook Pro which I’ve been using as a primary laptop during the pandemic. I’ve since customized it and learned to live it again. That said, it’s days are numbered.

My question:

Can I use my time machine back up on 2 to make 1 identical? Is there a way to keep the two laptops synchronous with time machine?

Comment: Just use migrate - works well I just did it between two macbook pro.

Comment: Getting them to the same state one time use Migration Assistant as commented. Keeping them in sync after is more difficult. If just your documents then iCloud or Dropbox or similar will work - Settings and other things in ~/Library are more complex

Comment: As @mmmmmm has said, and: Don't attempt to use TM as an ongoing sync tool - recipe for disaster. Alternative to iCloud, Dropbox, etc., I use Chronosync to keep Documents and some other folders synchronised between iMac and MacBook.